# Hibernate : add mandatory predicate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

We've introduced some roles in our app, and based on that role user must access filtered data.
We've built a service returning, according to the user role, the predicate that must be added to the request.

Is it possible to add that predicate in a a mandatory and automatic way to every request Hibernate will push to database ? Or is there another way to provide "mandatory filtering" to hibernate requests ?

First thought : try to override entity manager to add this behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a tough one, I haven't been able to find an elegant solution myself either yet. I tried quite a few approaches though: pre-checks (quick query before the "real query" to make sure the user has access to the entity they're querying), post-checks ("real query" first, then ensure the returned entity is accessible by the user), as well modifying the "real query" directly to have it take the current permissions into account. The latter is hard to get right, and I'm not aware of any Hibernate built-in solution I'm afraid.

Comment: I wouldn't go with overriding the EntityManager though, that might produce bugs that will be hard to debug once live. I've never tried it at least. For such dynamic queries, I guess the Criteria API should be used. I'd rather implement such logic in the repository/dao layer, where the query is getting built, by passing the current user around somehow. Hibernate also provides non-standard tools like `@Where` (which isn't what you need here, but there might be more "dynamic" ones).

Answer (score 1):

That's not really possible as the use case is pretty special IMO. It's rather rare that all tables have an equal set of columns for which you could apply a predicate.

You could try to override the `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl#statementPreparer` with a custom implementation that does this, but I don't think such a predicate applies onto all the SQL you are executing.

I don't know how this predicate looks like, but have you looked into the multi tenancy support in Hibernate? If all you need is some kind of `tenant = 123` predicate this is easy with Hibernate. If you need more, you will have to add this predicate somehow to every query that you use. Either in JPQL/HQL or Criteria.

If the syntax of the predicate is similar to JPQL/HQL, you could use [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) which is a query builder that accepts an extended JPQL variant with support for arbitrary depth path expressions. This could look like the following

```
CriteriaBuilder<Cat> criteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Cat.class, "cat");
criteriaBuilder.whereExpression("abc > 0 and def = 123"); // Your predicate
```

If the predicate is on a different abstraction level, you would need some kind of translation to the persistence level. This is where [Blaze-Expression](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-expression/#declarative-persistence-usage) could help you which is a toolkit to develop custom DSLs that can serialize onto a Blaze-Persistence query builder.

```
CriteriaBuilder<Cat> criteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Cat.class, "cat");

// Parse predicate against your context
ExpressionServiceFactory expressionServiceFactory = Expressions.forModel(domain);
ExpressionCompiler compiler = expressionServiceFactory.createCompiler();
ExpressionCompiler.Context context = compiler.createContext(
    Collections.singletonMap("c", domain.getType("CatModel"))
);
Predicate predicate = compiler.createPredicate("abc > 0 and def = 123", context);

// Apply predicate onto the query builder
ExpressionSerializer<WhereBuilder> serializer = expressionServiceFactory.createSerializer(WhereBuilder.class);
ExpressionSerializer.Context context = serializer.createContext(
    Collections.singletonMap("c", "cat")
);
serializer.serializeTo(context, predicate, criteriaBuilder);
```